# Why callback not working in angular service?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im making some tests with a js library with my Angular app and i noticed the following:

secret.service.ts:

```
   @Injectable()
   export class SecretService {
   public get adalConfig(): any {
     return {
           clientId: 'e71122a4-3998-416d-xxxxx',
           redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
           callback: () => console.log('not called!!')   // not work   
     };
   }
```

app.component.ts

```
  constructor(private adalService: AdalService,
              private secretService: SecretService,) { 
      this.adalService.init(this.secretService.adalConfig);
  }
```

When i register the `callback` property in the service, it never calls.
But if i change the app.component.ts to this:

```
 constructor(private adalService: AdalService,
              private secretService: SecretService,) { 

  let adalConfig: any = {
         clientId: this.secretService.adalConfig.clientId, 
         redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
  }     

  adalConfig.callback = () => console.log('now is called!') // like this works normally
  this.adalService.init(adalConfig);
}
```

Why when i set the callback function on the service its not called?

Comment: What's your code for `AdalService`?

Comment: First version is compiled to js like: adalConfig.prototype.callback and second adalConfig.callback?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you omitted some parenthesis. Try this:

```
this.adalService.init(this.secretService.adalConfig());
```

And change adalConfig method to:

```
adalConfig(): any {
    return {
        clientId: 'e71122a4-3998-416d-xxxxx',
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
        callback: () => console.log('not called!!')   // not work   
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**adalConfig** is a method and  you are passing like variable, in order to access the the return value of the method you need to call it.

```
constructor(private adalService: AdalService, private secretService: SecretService,) { 
       console.log(typeof this.secretService.adalConfig);// you can see function
       this.adalService.init(this.secretService.adalConfig());
  }
```

Comment: As far as I can see, `adalConfig` is a getter (marked with `get`) in SecretService, so there is no need to call it as a method.